# How would you rotate numbers in string using a rotational cypher?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, challenge-response

Hello I'm trying to solve the classic rotational cypher problem but im also trying to solve for when numbers are included in the string. So far this is the method I have been going about it using javascript:

```
function rotationalCipher(input, rotationFactor) {

const originalAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

return input.replace(/[a-z]/gi, letter => originalAlpha[originalAlpha.indexOf(letter)+rotationFactor]);
  

}
```

It works but it doesn't address the numbers within the string. Id be appreciative of any help.

Comment: If implemented correctly you should be able to simply add them to the `originalAlpha` string, however, I would expect some modulus calculation when calculating the new index. Why is the `i` flag there in your regex?

Comment: It was from some documentation that I copied I honestly don't know why. Also would you have an example by chance?

Comment: There are many many examples of Caesar ciphers. Better try it yourself. Create a function that calculates the index in the alphabet, then do the shift by using `+` and a modular operation using the size of the alphabet at the right side. Finally, convert back to a character code using the shifted index. Good luck!